# Video having problems on my phone in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have created an app for video demonstration using Codename one. I'm Facing some challenges when I'm running the app on my Google Android Phone as it does not allow a full screen view and also after the video is done playing, it does not go back or restart the video again. Another problem was that I had a button at the bottom at the borderlayout and each time I click the button, it corrupts the video and the video won't play anymore. These are codes used for my demonstration app [Demonstration App 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76n12pdpvjxt815/38b4844f-7747-4230-8cb4-880ece7d33d2-1467195034863-MyApplication-debug.apk?dl=0),  [Demonstration App2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfqlufsbze4mg7i/8149cdf3-b29e-49ef-a3f5-c475a47289c7-1467200181444-MyApplication-debug.apk?dl=0) .

```
@Override
protected void postMain1(Form f) {

    final MediaPlayer mp = findMpPresent();
    try {

        InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/sbuda.mp4");
        if (is != null) {
            mp.setDataSource(is, "video/mp4", null);
        } else {

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unclear since I can't see the stop/start etc with a GUI builder application.

You can use native on-device controls for playback using `setFullScreen`. Notice that this works nicely on the device but has no equivalent on the simulator.

Once playback is finished the media no longer exists as your input stream has been depleted. You will need to create a new Media object. You can use the completion callback (the Runnable argument) to detect the end of the media.

Comment: Is there any material(videos,links etc) that I can use to probably have an idea of what I'm expected to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if this sample is enough but we have a sample of video playback in the MediaPlayer docs: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_mediamanager_mediaplayer